# Divs are not showing up in the correct order

Tags: css

I have this CSS:

```
.overlay{
    opacity:0.5;
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:2;
}

.loginBox{
    width: 65%;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    height: 300px;
    z-index: 1001 !important;
    margin: auto;

    word-wrap:break-word;   
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<div class="loginBox">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><font size="4">Please log in or sign up to use this service</font></div>
            <div id="login" class="panel-body">
                 <!-- Panel stuff -->
```

And this is the background:

```
<div id="loginFormBackground" class="overlay"></div>
```

However, it shows up like this:

[image]

However, I want the black background to go behind loginBox. The z index is higher, why is it not showing in front of it?

After adding position:relative to the loginBox, my overlay looks like this:

[image]

Comment: maybe add position: relative for .loginBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z-index only applies to relative or absolute positioned elements.  Add `position: absolute;` or `position:relative;` to your login box and it will work.

Comment: Can you post the full HTML of your page?

Comment: Sure, it's up at https://chipperyman.com/commander_front. Or if you want, http://pastebin.com/1i8Yvkvv

Comment: Move your #loginFormBackground outside of all of the div's it's in currently so it's just under your <body>.  You don't want it nested inside anything.  Then when you change it to position:absolute; it will work correctly.